# Posting question and answer to a question that's already been asked before, to improve clarity and SEO?

Tags: discussion

I want to cover a question I see quite frequently on [reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reactjs) (the asynchronous nature of `setState()`), but few newcomers to the framework seem to know about it because it's not very apparent.

The question has already been asked and answered before several times, but it seems to me that finding these answers as a newbie might be hard because the root and/or cause of the problem isn't obvious from how the questions are formulated, thus making it hard to Google.

Would it be okay to ask a new question, with a clear and basic problem, and then answer it myself or would this be considered posting a duplicate? Perhaps this should go in the docs instead? 
I sometimes edit the title to make it more SEO-friendly, but sometimes you need the actual contents of the post to be clearer too.

I feel like I can help people find the answer to this common misconception if I can post a question which is basic, clear and easy to find from searching.

I guess this is a general question if it's okay to re-post something that's been answered before for the sake of increasing awareness and SEO for said problem.

Comment: Why not editing the one that we have?

Comment: As I explained above, sometimes the questions have too much code and too many explanations for the **specific application** of the OP. This makes it hard to find on search engines and hard to understand if you're new to programming.

Comment: How in the world would "too much code" and "too many explanations" make something harder to find on search engines? Search engines don't get overwhelmed and throw up their hands. More stuff is *more* helpful when indexing, not less.

Comment: @CodyGray, the problem is that it's too specific. If you're new, you wouldn't necessarily know what to search for.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. You can put in *any of the text* that appears in the question or answers, and it will appear in the search results. That makes finding it *easier*, not harder.

Comment: There are several examples of such artificial *canonical reference questions* in various tags; I think they're great and serve a good purpose, but they've often been received with mixed feelings in the past.

Comment: Canonical questions are great, but not when they're duplicates of existing questions. In that case, you just make the existing question into a canonical reference.

Comment: @CodyGray, yeah that's a good way to formulate it. If a canonical question is ok if it's a dupe. I guess the "problem" being that, while I would have full control on what I write in an answer, I don't have much over which question I'm answering (or rather, how the question is written)

Comment: You could write a canonical question and answer (make it a community wiki), but your bigger problem will be making it discoverable by the community around the specific tag. Perhaps you can find a chat room to collaborate with? The Python chat room [maintains a common question canon](http://sopython.com/canon/) to help here.  *Sometimes* the Python room decides that a new canonical is required and writes one, see [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response).

Comment: @MartijnPieters, interesting. I'll look into that.